# String literals incompatible with string type when intersecting object

Tags: flowtype

I'm trying to wrap my head around Flow.

This works as expected:

```
// @flow

type FontName = string
const doSomethingWithFontName = (fontName: FontName) => console.log(fontName)

type StrictFontName = 'Arial' | 'Verdana' | 'Times'
const doSomethingWithStrictFontName = (fontName: StrictFontName) => doSomethingWithFontName(fontName)

doSomethingWithStrictFontName('Times')
```

Calling `doSomethingWithFontName` from `doSomethingWithStrictFontName` works fine. I guess Flow sees that my enum `StrictFontName` contains only strings and thus I can call `doSomethingWithFontName` with either a string or a `StrictFontName`

However wrapping the variable in an object fails:

```
// @flow

type Typography = { 
  fontName?: string; 
}
const doSomethingWithTypography = (typography: Typography) => console.log(typography)

type StrictTypography = Typography & { 
  fontName?: 'Arial' | 'Verdana' | 'Times'; 
}
const doSomethingWithStrictTypography = (typography: StrictTypography) => {
  doSomethingWithTypography(typography)
}

doSomethingWithStrictTypography({fontName: 'Times'})
```

I'm only forwarding our strict object to a more loose function here, why does this not work? Flow can tell `StrictTypography`'s `fontName` is still a string right?

I've read this [thread](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5895#issuecomment-369735977) and came up with making the supertype an interface as a workaround:

```
// @flow

// Interface instead of type
interface Styles { 
  fontName?: string; 
}

const doSomethingWithStyling = (styles: Styles) => console.log(styles)

type StrictStyles  = Styles & { 
  fontName?: 'Arial' | 'Verdana' | 'Times'; 
}
const doSomethingWithStrictStyling = (styles: StrictStyles) => {
  doSomethingWithStyling(styles)
}

doSomethingWithStrictStyling({fontName: 'Times'})
```

That seems to work, but I'm not sure if it's the right approach here. Also if I import this interface I get a `Use of future reserved word in strict mode`...

You can find the playground [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiSgJIHIC2oAuAnATwEsA7Acz1lHnwEMAHULQ0ACwFM6ATUO-WAFdSvAGJx4AOlDJUAYgWKlyuaFAAVNsQDONWPgDWuuro4APBhwDGuDrxUPFa5GrW5Cl0KNilcAOTosDlAAXlBtAjJyRFdQKx8I0G5YAGVYINwtCgB1YkzvXwCg0NAACkgff0COAC4vSqKOAEpQgD44hNhoDkk4cnKG6qaY1xG3D2CUyJsCquKwjABBfGI6aAxQAB9QDAA1DnxuOlI6De2MdWIg7QwxjtJE5LSMrPJczKmVmcH5sorC6p1T7Eb4AoItELtJ7pDiZKLvNizRoDMHNFyuaEveF5NjA0FzDilC5XDg3YYoMAAYTW0CioAABpjYa8EUjqvTQJABDhGakYXCcji8bg2UEOfB9EZOWQejJUGhQORBKTdOIEOEOKS8Gw6LhmKwOKRBDzhaKOBz4r46GRdD5oKwIisKMYRNrBLoFVZjnEaXKwLznszsfkfuaaDjQBwcQc+OFIhRQPpY-TTaH6bIwKBHI4vNboKAaqU1NmHM47u5POoPLByPQGGxWGEAN4yWJqf4EgD8dUdUQA3K3XABfO6Wx58rGCzJVhg1usNkqlCtzxgNuozlf1wgQ9pjro9PpL6u11fbu7liagYUbk9bko3+esABkoBbd3boe7O2Wq3WWx2+yHMcpz-sS1wYAOdwjrEY56kyApvEK0y4A+p6Lsut5rleyGoVuO6vu+SQTkGU5sLhDZHrOmFnrE0GjLE8EskhXwocej6lE2HaNHUYGkhgQ7kvK2CJqQ9qcvo8D8NwdJCPgcYsYmABGABW1h6rg1B0Mw+jBHAsDaMEkDCDYxA+OwBwcAANDQC7JFqcK6KQsB6hKhids4qBqvAPqkHgHDQPm15saeGC6Fx1SgDocbEAFsa9gmKzkGwuCdhmxYlsoajZJK-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)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things happening here.

By defining the intersection `Styles & { fontName?: 'Arial' | 'Verdana' | 'Times' }` you create a type that might have a property `fontName` that must be of type `string` and also one of the specific strings you put. This isn't possible because if the string is `'Verdana'` or something, then it cannot also be *any other* string. This is a weird concept but basically by narrowing a type to a specific string, you're saying it can't be other strings. And by making it `string` you're saying it can be any string. This type can't be fulfilled.

The reason why it works in your first example is because of [*variance*](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/). Basically, the first, more broad function accepts `string` but since it's a function argument, it's *contravariant* and allows less specific types, such as `'foo'`, `'bar'`, and, yes, `'Verdana'`. Flow automatically interprets function argument types as contravariant, and function return types as covariant.

So what you probably intended is this:

```
type StrictTypography = { 
  fontName?: 'Arial' | 'Verdana' | 'Times'; 
}
```

But it still doesn't work, because though the the argument is contravariant, the object property `fontName` is *not*, so now it's only satisfied by broad `string`s and exactly broad `string`s. To make it contravariant, use the `+` symbol:

```
type Typography = {
  +fontName?: string; 
}
```

[Completed example.](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAKuD2BzATgQzACxFAvFA3gFBRQDUAZvAHbAByqAthAPwBcUAzsMgJZWIBuKIQC+hAMbUuUACbwAyvCbAMfRAHUeKuGCRpM2PAApQulOizsdeiyACUuAHxRJVDvAA2EAHQekJhHMDO0JCU2h5bh5xYGsgrFwCYihKGnomNigAcgBBXlQPLKgAH2yANQhkGVQqVCLSrJgeJg4soVEJKWBZBSUIFTVNFUjeGLj9BONTGwN2EejYwIn7JySSOUVlVX4hjHHbALNlkLFCDb6Bna0MebGlg-wU6jpGCHYsiqqauqgREPOtoNrrdFkcHn8gA)

Comment: I think that makes sense. So adding the `+` symbol here changes the `fontName` to accept broad strings AND other strings that boil down to a broad string, like one of `'Arial' | 'Verdana' | 'Times'`. Right?

Comment: However, that does not change the fact that I can't express a way to make the string optional. The following concept can't be expressed with flow: 
1) a function expects an object that might contain a fontName or contains nothing. 2) another function expects an object that might contain one of the three predefined fontNames or nothing. 3) the second function calls the first function with it's argument.

Comment: @Tieme `+` makes it accept the same type (`string`) and subtypes. All exact strings are subtypes of `string`, since `string` is the set of all types that are individual strings. As for your second comment, why not? Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but doesn't this example work: https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAKuD2BzATgQzACxFAvFA3gFBRQDUAZvAHbAByqAthAPwBcUAzsMgJZWIBuKIQC+hAMbUuUACbwAyvCbAMfRAHUeKuGCRpM2PAApQulOizsdeiyACUuAHxRJVDvAA2EAHQekJhHMDO0JCU2h5bh5xYGsgrFwCYihKGnomNigAcgBBXlQPLKgAH2yANQhkGVQqVCLSrJgeJg4soVEJKWBZBSUIFTVNFUjeGLj9BONTGwN2EejYwIn7JySSOUVlVX4hjHHbALNlkLFCDb6Bna0MebGlg-wROyA

Comment: Check. Yeah that works! Not sure why it didn't work when I tried that yesterday... Thanks! Could you maybe add this example to your answer for completeness for future readers?

Comment: > To make it contravariant, use the + symbol
This is confusing, the documentation says that `+` is for covariant: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/#toc-interface-property-variance-read-only-and-write-only